# why button doesnt work in Phonegap project with json and JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm newbie for JQuery Mobile & json (Phonegap project), i'm very confused why button doesnt work in Phonegap project with json and JQuery Mobile?

I have JQM HTML5 coding like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugin/cordova/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="plugin/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugin/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        $(document).on("click", "button#login", function(){ homePage(); });
        function homePage() {
            $.mobile.loading("show");
                 $.ajax({  
 url: "http://.../abcd/authenticate.php",
  type: "POST",  
  data: "username=" + $("#username").val()+"&password=" + $("#password").val(),
dataType:"jsonp",
  success: function(status)
  {  
  if(status.success == "true") 
    { location.href='home.html'; 
  } else { 
         location.href='nilai.html'; 
    }
  }, 
           timeout: 30000,    
           error:function(){ alert("error..");  
});

        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="login" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Login</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know why? Thank you. Im sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are semantic errors in your code -- there are missing braces in the JS and unclosed DIV towards the bottom. This is at least does not throw an error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugin/cordova/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="plugin/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugin/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            $(document).on("click", "button#login", function () {
                homePage();
            });
            function homePage() {
                $.mobile.loading("show");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://.../abcd/authenticate.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "username=" + $("#username").val() + "&password=" + $("#password").val(),
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (status) {
                        if (status.success == "true") {
                            location.href = 'home.html';
                        } else {
                            location.href = 'nilai.html';
                        }
                    },
                    timeout: 30000,
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error..");
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="login" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you user1756848! Solved.. :D